# How to animate the movement of inline-block items on page resize (ideally using css)?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

**HTML**

```
<div class="mosaic_tile" style="background:rgb(255,0,0);">
</div>
<div class="mosaic_tile" style="background:rgb(0,255,0);">
</div>
<div class="mosaic_tile" style="background:rgb(0,0,255);">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mosaic_tile{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/suse008b/

Notice how when the width of the page is less than the total width of the elements on a said line an element is moved to the next line. Is there anyway for me to animate the movement of the elements as they reblock?

Edit:
I found an example. Something similar to the portfolio portion of this webpage.
http://www.socialfix.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the example site you mentioned they are using a javascript library called Isotope for that effect.

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Here's a **demo** of Isotope.js:  https://codepen.io/ashleedawg/pen/WNNqeZQ